# Issues writing to json files Unity android Build (Focus 3)

Tags: c#, android, json, unity-game-engine

I am saving data-files on the persistant datapath of the android device focus 3 I am building for. The current file saving and editing system seems to work well in the editor and works if i create and write to the file in the same "session" but as soon as the scene or build is reloaded then i get the following error when trying to write to the file.

```
02-06 09:33:52.696 16111 16133 E Unity   : IOException: Sharing violation on path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Project.ProjectName/files/gamedata.json
02-06 09:33:52.696 16111 16133 E Unity   :   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
```

What could be the cause of this. I use the toJson() function to write and read the plaintext file-class.
`gameData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(text);`

```
        FileStream iStream = new FileStream(plaintext_saveFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(iStream);

        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameData);
        sWriter.Write(jsonString);
```

Additionally when trying to implement a simple AES cryptography solution i get the following error:

```
02-06 09:31:19.699 16111 16133 E Unity   : CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 82.
02-06 09:31:19.699 16111 16133 E Unity   :   at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.ThrowBadPaddingException (System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode padding, System.Int32 length, System.Int32 position) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
02-06 09:31:19.699 16111 16133 E Unity   :   at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalDecrypt (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

I mostly attempted to follow this tutorial: https://videlais.com/2021/02/28/encrypting-game-data-with-unity/

I have tried changing the filestream mode from create to openandcreate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're still using the default package name ("com.Project.ProjectName").  Unity may have some additional protection for data under that name (not sure, though).  I recommend going to Project Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> and set the Package Name field to a unique value.  Then try again.

Comment: I altered the name as it contains the name of the company I am currently employed. The package is not the default package.